# jquery remove parent of parent cur.element

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi I don't remove parnet.

My code:

```
  <div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll">
   <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
      <label class="prdctfltr_ft_">
        <input type="checkbox" value="">
         <span>
            <img src="" onerror="delNoneOptionFilters(this)" class="product_filter_none_option">
            <script>function delNoneOptionFilters( x ){ $(x).closest('label').remove; }</script>
         </span>
      </label>
      <label class="prdctfltr_ft_popularity">
        <input type="checkbox" value="popularity">
        <span>Popularity</span>
      </label>
      <label class="prdctfltr_ft_rating">
        <input type="checkbox" value="rating">
        <span>Average rating</span>
      </label>
      <label class="prdctfltr_ft_date">
        <input type="checkbox" value="date">
        <span>Newness</span>
      </label>
        <label class="prdctfltr_ft_price">
        <input type="checkbox" value="price">
        <span>Price: low to high</span>
      </label>
      <label class="prdctfltr_ft_price-desc">
        <input type="checkbox" value="price-desc">
        <span>Price: high to low</span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want delete label class="prdctfltr_ft_"

Answer (score 1):

`remove` is not a property It is a `function` you have to use like this `$(x).closest('label').remove()`.

```js
function delNoneOptionFilters( x ){
$(x).closest('label').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prdctfltr_add_scroll">
   <div class="prdctfltr_checkboxes">
      <label class="prdctfltr_ft_">
        <input type="checkbox" value="">
         <span>
           <button onclick="delNoneOptionFilters(this)">delete</button>
           
         </span>
      </label>
      <label class="prdctfltr_ft_popularity"><input type="checkbox" value="popularity"><span>Popularity</span></label><label class="prdctfltr_ft_rating"><input type="checkbox" value="rating"><span>Average rating</span></label><label class="prdctfltr_ft_date"><input type="checkbox" value="date"><span>Newness</span></label><label class="prdctfltr_ft_price"><input type="checkbox" value="price"><span>Price: low to high</span></label><label class="prdctfltr_ft_price-desc"><input type="checkbox" value="price-desc"><span>Price: high to low</span></label>                       
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:-

```
function delNoneOptionFilters( x ){ $(x).parents('label').remove(); }
```